# NSClassFromString loading class from a library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

For somewhat complex reasons, I'm needing to access a class from a library I'm writing externally via `NSClassFromString`. I've tested the method (`NSClassFromString`) on other libraries and it works with otherwise hidden/internal classes, but it won't work on mine. I build the library as a static library with the `-ObjC` flag, and I build the project with `-ObjC` as well. What do I need to do to get the library class to register properly with the lib so I can access it externally?

To be a bit more specific, I'm building a library with associated submodules. The user can add/remove submodules as needed, and I need the main lib to compile and run if they are missing, hence `NSClassFromString` on submodule classes and fail gracefully if they don't exist. I'm compiling the submodules into individual .a files.

Comment: Are you linking your project agains the library?

Comment: I added the library to the test project, yes. Not sure if that's what you're asking. And it's referenced in Link Binary with Libraries.

Comment: Try using the `-all_load` linker flag.

Comment: -all_load is set as well in the test project. Not in the library build; does it need to be set there?

edit: set -all_load in both the library and the project and still no dice

Comment: OK, we are going to chalk this one up to XCode fail. The new project automatically set library paths to a completely different project for some reason and was referencing old and/or incorrect files.